# Is there a way to create interceptor that intercept a list modification

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

So suppose I have a list that contains product information like this

```
data class Tile(
  val pattern: PatternEnum
)

class Warehouse {
  val tiles = mutableListOf<Tile>()
}
```

I want to create an inteceptor that intercept everytime the list gets updated like this

```
class ListProductInterceptor {
  lateinit var type: ProductTypeEnum

  constructor(type: ProductTypeEnum){
    this.type = type
  }

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var qaService: QaService

  fun intercept(list: List<Tile>){
    // if list is empty remove product type from qa service
    if (list.isEmpty()){
      qaService.removeProductType(this.type)
    }
    // if it's not then add it but not if already exist 
    else if (!qaService.typeList.contains(this.type)) {
      qaService.addProductType(this.type)
    }
  }
}
```

So yeah I could do it in the business layer like this.

```
interface IWarehouseService {
  fun updateProduct()
  fun destroyProduct()
  // etc.. a lot of methods that modify the list
}

class WarehouseService: IWarehouseService {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var qaService: QaService

  val tiles = mutableListOf<Tile>()
  
  override fun destroyProduct() {
    // some business logic here
    // and after it modify tiles list I have to check it again
    if (tiles.isEmpty()){
      qaService.removeProductType(ProductTypeEnum.Tile)
    }
    else if (!qaService.typeList.contains(ProductTypeEnum.Tile)) {
      qaService.addProductType(ProductTypeEnum.Tile)
    }
  }
}
```

but the problem is, the service has a lot of methods that modify the list of tile and if the other guy add a new method I'm not sure if his method will modify the list or not if it does would he check it for me? And the service also has other list with different type that I have to check it the same way. So I think it might be good if I can create an interceptor and pass the type of product as an argument because all it does is check if it the list is empty and modify productType of the QA service. Is there a way to archive something like this or similar or even better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not use a `var` with a `List` instead of a `val` with a `MutableList`? Then you can use a custom setter, or you can use a delegate like `Delegates.vetoable`. By the way, there is no reason for `type` to be `lateinit` since you initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: yeah my bad. I type everything in a hurry.